# Error running a microstrategy report on website using Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, microstrategy

I have been trying to run a Microstrategy report on a website, and tried the html and js approach. As a test, i wrote this (the code below), but i keep getting errors and the report doesn't appear  in my iframe.  I checked the inspector in Chrome and kept getting this error -

Refused to display 'https://www.microstrategy.com/us/free/express/analytics-express-sign-in?documentID=D3F9920011E43A6B000000802FC73DA5&OrgId=30650#sign-in' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
  <SCRIPT>

    function run() {
       var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
       var idx = sel.selectedIndex;
       switch (idx) {
          case 0:
          document.getElementById('test').style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById('test').contentWindow.location.href="https://cloud11.microstrategy.com/MicroStrategy/servlet/mstrWeb?pg=shareAgent&apptype=2&documentID=D3F9920011E43A6B000000802FC73DA5&OrgId=30650&RRUid=1872948";
          break;
          case 1:
          document.getElementById('test').style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById('test').contentWindow.location.href="https://cloud11.microstrategy.com/MicroStrategy/servlet/mstrWeb?pg=shareAgent&apptype=2&documentID=D3F9920011E43A6B000000802FC73DA5&OrgId=30650&RRUid=1872948";
          break;
          default:
          document.getElementById('test').style.visibility = "hidden";
      }

       function hide() {
         document.getElementById('test').style.visibility = "hidden";
       } 

      }
 </SCRIPT>
 <iframe id="test" src="about:blank" width="800" height="500" style="visibility:hidden;">
 </iframe>
 <br>
 <select id="sel">
  <option>Report1</option>
  <option>Report2</option>
 </select>
 <br>
 <br>
 <input type="button" value="Run" onclick="run();"/>
 <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="hide();"/>

</body>
</html>
```

After getting that error, i decided to add "./" in the URL, but only got this as an error:

GET file:///C:/wamp/www/ADLScorm/https://cloud11.microstrategy.com/MicroStrateg…pe=2&documentID=D3F9920011E43A6B000000802FC73DA5&OrgId=30650&RRUid=1872948 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Please how do i resolve this?

PS(I initially used document.getElementById('test').src as well. Still got the same error)

Answer (score 0):

You are facing a Cross(X)-Domain security policy issue. Your page is hosted on domain A and you want domain B to be loaded in your iframe. Browsers do not allow this. Domain B must allow domain A in its response header.

Comment: Please is there anyway i can fix this domain security policy issue?